# Calling events for n buttons on the form

Tags: c#, events, button

In my previus post I asked how to create a set of n draggable buttons, which worked fine, but I'm now working on the following:

I placed an image on the form, and loaded a coordinate matrix, so that when I also drag the image, the buttons "follow the image", I'm trying to acomplish it by calling an event when the button is finished being dragged, calling an event and transforming "image coordinates" to "form coordinates". It works fine for just one, but  the problem arises when I place n buttons, since I don't know how to "recognize" which button called the event, I'll show you how I did my stuff:

```
 int x, y;

 //Creates a set of four buttons with an icon
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
     x = rnd.Next(1, this.Width - 30);
     y = rnd.Next(1, this.Height - 30);
     botonCustom newboton = new botonCustom(32, 32, new Point(x, y), imageList1);

     //New event for each button (Is it ok to do?)
     //I tried to call the same function newboton_Move, since i do not know how to create an event for each button
     newboton.Move += new EventHandler(newboton_Move);

     //Name the button and writes it on a lablel
     newboton.Description = EtiDiamond[i];
     DiamondButton.Add(newboton);
     this.Controls.Add(newboton);
  }
```

Here is the function being called:

```
private void newboton_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Here i use the coordinates transform method, i won't place the code because
   // its too big and it goes against the rules :P, i think if i could somehow know which button called this...         
}
```

Thanks for reading this

Comment: You have to cast sender to Button. Then you will know which one is call the event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sender` is the button that raised the event

```
var myButton = sender as Button;
```

Comment: So let's say, the sender is the 3rd button, and i want to change its location, could i do  myButton.Location=new point(x,y); and will this  modify the location of the sender?